# Jpackage with modular application difficulties to create installer

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jpackage

I tried to create an installer for my java fx app but it's not working. I use a jar for the first try. The installer was created but the application didn't launched. I figured it was the method for non modular application. I tried the modular application way : `jpackage -n eurogip --input installer\input -p C:\libjava --module eurogrip/eurogrip --vendor "Practical Devs"` but it responds that the module doesnt' exist i tried different writing for module without eurgogrip/ ..... and typed java --list-modules. My module doesn't not exist at all. How can i deploy my modular application ?

Here is my module-info.java.

```
module eurogrip {
requires java.desktop;
requires javafx.controls;
requires transitive javafx.base;
requires transitive javafx.graphics;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires java.sql;
requires jdom;
requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
opens eurogrip.model to javafx.base;
opens eurogrip.controller to javafx.fxml;
exports eurogrip.controller;
exports eurogrip to javafx.graphics;
```

}

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, i found the solution in module path i had to add my eurogrip jar --module i think it's to precise it is the main module in fact but need the jar in --module-path with other jar. I was in the folder of my project and thought it will be ok but i have now an other problem (tired) of automatic module jdom which cannot be use with jlink i'll do some search again otherwise i'll post. Thanks

Comment: Jlink does not work with automatic modules. One way to procede can be found here https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX